# where to find the "java" javadoc for scala.collection.immutable.Iterable?

Tags: java, scala, akka

I am using Akka with java.

I see  that AbstractActorContext has a method :

```
scala.collection.immutable.Iterable<akka.actor.ActorRef> children();
```

How do I get the java javadoc for

```
  scala.collection.immutable.Iterable ?
```

I can only find the scala version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no java javadoc for it, because it's a scala class, written in scala. (It does have scaladoc available). While it's possible to use scala classes from java (and the scaladoc for it will help you with this), the APIs will be designed for use from scala and probably not very idiomatic in java. In java code you should probably use the

```
java.lang.Iterable<ActorRef> getChildren();
```

method of `AbstractActorContext` instead.

Answer (score 1):

[link](http://static.javadoc.io/org.scala-lang/scala-library/2.8.0.RC7/scala/collection/immutable/Iterable$.html)

I think this might be what you are looking for